# c++: print a string with specified length

Tags: c++, printf, space, cout

In C++, **using printf-s** I want to write a char array  (etc `char asd[50]`) to console with a specified 50 space
(similar like `"%.2d"` method at decimals, if the string shorter fill it with spaces....)

Tried %50s and %.50s methods, both of them wronged my charachters....

I can (hardly) accept  answers, but then calculat with the fact, i use a charachter array, so its not wrok to cout<

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/ - various options to format stuff

Comment: have you tried google it? the `cout string width fill` would be a good keywords.

Comment: as i said, i want to use printf, not cout streams, and the %50s troll my charachters

Comment: @user3063349: Is there any good *technical* reason why you want to use `printf`? It is both less safe and less flexible than C++ streams.

Comment: I'll bet you have more significant problems if using %50s gives garbage as output. I have no clue what you mean by the last sentence, though. Character arrays work fine with `cout`.

Comment: it only write a 1 number to my console....curius

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you find it useful,

```
#include <iomanip>
void prints(const char * s)
{
    cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(50) << s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A used a for loop with printfs (using %c) to write it, and after the \0 charachter it write spaces , so problem solved

```
for(int j=0;j<50;j++)
        {
            printf("%c",asd[j]);
        }
```

Comment: So based on this answer, your array consists of a string, followed by a null character, followed by spaces (which would have been good information to put in the question). In that case, `std::cout << std::string(asd, asd + 50);` would have the same behaviour. So would `std::cout << std::setw(50) << std::left << asd;`.

Comment: so also would:  `fwrite(asd, sizeof(char), 50, stdout) ;`

Comment: I am usually not use printf/scanf methods, so i googled to use %s to char arrays that follow it with the null charachter, didnt know thats not a "usual" method for them, and need to specifie it, sorry